# How to make the 1st element of list of lists to match the order of elements in another list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can I make the 1st element of list of lists to match the order of elements in another list? For example:

```
list1 = [3, 7, 1, 10, 4]
list2 = [[1,0],[3,2],[4,11],[7,9],[10,1]]

newlist = [[3,2],[7,9],[1,0],[10,1],[4,11]]
```

Comment: Why not loop over `list1`, find the corresponding item in `list2` and append it to `newlist`? Or use `sorted` with the index of each first element in `list1` as `key` function?

Comment: Does `list2` always contain exactly the `list1` values as first value, and each exactly once?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.index`:

```py
list1 = [3, 7, 1, 10, 4]
list2 = [[1, 0], [3, 2], [4, 11], [7, 9], [10, 1]]

newlist = sorted(list2, key=lambda l: list1.index(l[0]))
print(newlist)
```

Prints:

```
[[3, 2], [7, 9], [1, 0], [10, 1], [4, 11]]
```

---

If the lists are large, I'd suggest to create a mapping from `list1` and use that in the sorting key function:

```
m = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(list1)}
newlist = sorted(list2, key=lambda l: m[l[0]])

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the firsts in the second list are always a permutation of the first list (i.e., if that's not a misleading example):

```
firsts = next(zip(*list2))
first2full = dict(zip(firsts, list2))
newlist = [*map(first2full.get, list1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LDoIwEEX3/YpZUjIxDJCgC76EdEEUtAnWBmpQf75OHy5Mmuk059zc2re7PUxztKv3i94cQQ9Dg9AhEJ8KoVUigDqAgbBSyLzm2SIRXx2eeLJJSol9NC6KSckshqKRU0qIWa@b29g108sVH22LMtZImVA9P5eF8UWfE04BhJ9lpj2soa28j5nH1OE6ueSR5Ca7auOKrMv/J/Q9hD9L778)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this. But be careful when you have repititive *first* elements in **list2** elements !

```
a = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        if list1[i] == list2[j][0]:
            a.append(list2[j])

print(a)
```

Comment: "Python developer with 3 years experience" but you don't know how to iterate without indices?

Comment: @KellyBundy, bro it's the one of the solutions. And wasn't repeated above.